# ArcPy: ERROR 000584: Implementation of this Tool's Validate is invalid. Failed to execute (LayerToKML)

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, arcgis-pro, google-earth, kmz

I am writing a script that takes all shapefiles within a folder, defines a coordinate system for them, then reprojects that coordinate system to WGS84, then finally converts the reprojected layer to KMZ file format. This is done so I can have an easier time passing data to be represented in Google Earth Pro. I am running this script in ArcGIS Pro.

This is the script.

```
import arcpy
import os

#set workspace environment
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/data"

#set the output folder
output_folder = "C:/data/test"

#Use the ListFiles method to identify all shapefiles in workspace
layers = [layer for layer in arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp*") if not layer.endswith(".sr.lock" or ".shp.xml")]

#Loop through the list
for layer in layers:
    try:
        print(f"Processing {layer}...")
        
        # Define coordinate system
        arcpy.DefineProjection_management(layer, 26949)

        # Define the output file for the reprojected shapefile
        shapefile_name = os.path.splitext(layer)[0]
        output_shapefile = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{shapefile_name}_reprojected.shp")

        # Delete output shapefile if it already exists
        if arcpy.Exists(output_shapefile):
            arcpy.Delete_management(output_shapefile)

        # Reproject the shapefiles
        arcpy.Project_management(layer, output_shapefile, 4326)

        print(f"Successfully reprojected {layer} to {output_shapefile}")
        
        # Check that output shapefile was created successfully
        if not arcpy.Exists(output_shapefile):
            raise Exception(f"Failed to create {output_shapefile}")
        
        # Define the output path for the KMZ file
        output_kmz = os.path.join(output_folder, f"{shapefile_name}.kmz")
        
        # Delete output KMZ file if it already exists
        if arcpy.Exists(output_kmz):
            arcpy.Delete_management(output_kmz)
        
        # Convert the reprojected shapefile to KMZ format
        arcpy.conversion.LayerToKML(output_shapefile, output_kmz)

        print(f"Successfully converted {output_shapefile} to {output_kmz}")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to process {layer}: {str(e)}")
```

The error that occurs is the following:

> Processing airports.shp...
> Successfully reprojected airports.shp to C:/data/Test\airports_reprojected.shp
> Failed to process airports.shp: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
> ERROR 000584: Implementation of this Tool's Validate is invalid.
> Failed to execute (LayerToKML).

Indicating there is something wrong with the execution of the LayerToKML tool. If I try manually input airports_reprojected.shp to the LayerToKML tool the script works. So I am not sure where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good example of why you need to be reading the help file for the tool, especially the [parameter section](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/layer-to-kml.htm#GUID-136D2A7E-4955-4BB7-8115-34FF718A0170). It clearly states that the data type of the first parameter is a **Feature Layer**.

In your code you are providing a **Feature Class**, the source data, not a layer object.

You can use the Make Feature Layer tool to convert a Feature Class into a Feature Layer.